i want to low high to be centered according to the model that is used
This is my current code. And I cant make low high columns in FPCR Prophet Update to allign. Also Pick-up is right leaning while and not in the middle of low high. How can i achieve a better allignment?  I tried chatgpt but gives me rubbish.
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
\toprule
Model & \multicolumn{2}{r}{Pick-up} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{FPCR-Prophet} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{FPCR-Prophet-update} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{Prophet} \\
Version var. & low & high & low & high & low & high & low & high \\
\midrule
h=0 & 1.83 & 1.79 & 1.47 & 5.14 & 2.07 & 2.13 & 0.82 & 6.88 \\
h=1 & 2.74 & 2.67 & 1.32 & 5.52 & 1.97 & 3.17 & 0.83 & 6.12 \\
h=2 & 5.06 & 5.18 & 1.2 & 5.74 & 1.92 & 4.1 & 0.9 & 6.75 \\
h=3 & 8.57 & 9.91 & 1.13 & 6.45 & 2.69 & 5.86 & 0.92 & 7.43 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Simulation results }
\label{your-label}
\end{table}



Welcome. // To the right are Related links, always worth to inspect.

The alignment of the Prophet label is because you specify r in the \multicolumn; use c instead. For the other \multicolumns it would be desirable to use c too, but for the wider ones (FPCR-Prophet & FPCR-Prophet-update) that won't help, as they are just too wide, i.e., wider than the two columns under them combined. LaTeX doesn't have good provisions to do this kond of nesting alignments, but I think a simple solution would be to shift the two low columns a bit to the right. How much, you have to find out by trial and error. I tried 3mm and 9mm respectively. This gives me the following solution:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}\\
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll>{\hspace{3mm}}ll>{\hspace{9mm}}llll}
\toprule
Model & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pick-up} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FPCR-Prophet} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FPCR-Prophet-update} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Prophet} \\
Version var. & low & high & low & high & low & high & low & high \\
\midrule
h=0 & 1.83 & 1.79 & 1.47 & 5.14 & 2.07 & 2.13 & 0.82 & 6.88 \\
h=1 & 2.74 & 2.67 & 1.32 & 5.52 & 1.97 & 3.17 & 0.83 & 6.12 \\
h=2 & 5.06 & 5.18 & 1.2 & 5.74 & 1.92 & 4.1 & 0.9 & 6.75 \\
h=3 & 8.57 & 9.91 & 1.13 & 6.45 & 2.69 & 5.86 & 0.92 & 7.43 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\\\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}
\caption{Simulation results }
\label{your-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}

The two rules are to show the text width, and as you see the whole table gets too wide with the LaTeX article class.

We may try to make the table a bit smaller by using the \small font and by removing some intercolumn space with @{}. The shifts then become 1mm and 7mm.
\begin{table}[h]
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}\\
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{lll>{\hspace{1mm}}ll>{\hspace{7mm}}ll@{}ll}
\toprule
Model & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pick-up} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{FPCR-Prophet} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{FPCR-Prophet-update} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Prophet} \\
Version var. & low & high & low & high & low & high & low & high \\
\midrule
h=0 & 1.83 & 1.79 & 1.47 & 5.14 & 2.07 & 2.13 & 0.82 & 6.88 \\
h=1 & 2.74 & 2.67 & 1.32 & 5.52 & 1.97 & 3.17 & 0.83 & 6.12 \\
h=2 & 5.06 & 5.18 & 1.2 & 5.74 & 1.92 & 4.1 & 0.9 & 6.75 \\
h=3 & 8.57 & 9.91 & 1.13 & 6.45 & 2.69 & 5.86 & 0.92 & 7.43 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\\\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}
\caption{Simulation results }
\label{your-label}
\end{table}



Thank you Pieter!

I'd use a legend, rather than longish headers.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  *{8}{S[table-format=1.2]}
}
\toprule
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Version \\ var. \end{tabular}} &
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Model} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Pick-up} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{FPCR-P} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{FPCR-PU} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Prophet} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
& {low} & {high} & {low} & {high} & {low} & {high} & {low} & {high} \\
\midrule
$h=0$ & 1.83 & 1.79 & 1.47 & 5.14 & 2.07 & 2.13 & 0.82 & 6.88 \\
$h=1$ & 2.74 & 2.67 & 1.32 & 5.52 & 1.97 & 3.17 & 0.83 & 6.12 \\
$h=2$ & 5.06 & 5.18 & 1.2 & 5.74 & 1.92 & 4.1 & 0.9 & 6.75 \\
$h=3$ & 8.57 & 9.91 & 1.13 & 6.45 & 2.69 & 5.86 & 0.92 & 7.43 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \footnotesize FPCR-P: FPCR-Prophet;\qquad FPCR-PU: FPCR-Prophet-update%
}}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Simulation results}
\label{your-label}

\end{table}

\end{document}


